# How to fix missing JPEG support in Qt 4.8 under Linux KDE4

Tags: linux, qt, jpeg, pyside, kde4

**[UPDATE]** Upgrading to python 2.7.6 and Qt 4.8.7 appears to make this problem go away and JPEG support is provided. Whereas before creating a QPixmap object using a path to a .jpeg/.jpg file would produce an object for which isNull() was always True, now I get a valid QPixmap object.

---

The platform in question is a CentOS 7.2 system with KDE4 as the default desktop environment. Qt 4.8.5 is installed along with PySide 1.2.2. JPEG support seems to be missing for some reason.

```
>>> from PySide import QtGui
>>> pprint(QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageForamts())
[PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('BW'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('EPS'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('EPSF'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('EPSI'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('EXR'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('PCX'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('PSD'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('RAS'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('RGB'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('RGBA'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('SGI'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('TGA'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('XCF'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('bmp'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('bw'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('dds'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('eps'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('epsf'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('epsi'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('exr'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('jp2'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('pbm'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('pcx'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('pgm'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('pic'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('png'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('ppm'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('psd'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('ras'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('rgb'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('rgba'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('sgi'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('tga'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('xbm'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('xcf'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('xpm'),
 PySide.QtCore.QByteArray('xv')]
```

As you can see there is no JPEG support listed. The Qt imageformats contains:

```
libqgif.so
libqico.so
libqjpeg.so
libqmng.so
libqsvg.so
libqtga.so
libqtiff.so
```

Doing an ldd on libqjpeg.so yields:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc43530000)
libQtGui.so.4 => /lib64/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f2c11977000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /lib64/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f2c1148c000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2c1126f000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2c10f67000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2c10c65000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2c10a4e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2c1068d000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2c1048b000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2c10153000)
libpng15.so.15 => /lib64/libpng15.so.15 (0x00007f2c0ff28000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2c0fd12000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f2c0fa6b000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2c0f81b000)
libSM.so.6 => /lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f2c0f613000)
libICE.so.6 => /lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f2c0f3f6000)
libXi.so.6 => /lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f2c0f1e6000)
libXrender.so.1 => /lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f2c0efdc000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /lib64/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f2c0edd1000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f2c0ebcb000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f2c0e9c0000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /lib64/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f2c0e7bc000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f2c0e580000)
libXext.so.6 => /lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f2c0e36e000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f2c0e02f000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2c0de2b000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2c0dc23000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2c128b9000)
libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f2c0da1a000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f2c0d815000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f2c0d5ea000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f2c0d3c8000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f2c0d1c3000)
```

I see no missing shared libraries, but also nothing that looks like a JPEG library. QT_PLUGIN_PATH points to /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins, and /usr/lib64/kde4/plugins/imageformats contains these files:

```
kimg_dds.so
kimg_eps.so
kimg_exr.so
kimg_jp2.so
kimg_pcs.so
kimg_pic.so
kimg_psd.so
kimg_ras.so
kimg_rgb.so
kimg_tga.so
kimg_xcf.so
kimg_xview.so
```

So no kimg_jpeg.so (if there even is such a thing), and clearly kimg_jp2.so isn't providing JPEG support. So what am I missing?

Comment: jp2 should be the jpeg format you want. For historical reason JPEG is a compression algorithm not  a file format, and JPEG files are in fact JP2 IFF files.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean. No, `jp2` is [JPEG 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000), which is a completely different standard. The *libqjpeg.so* plugin should provide `jpg/jpeg`, but it is not listed. By default, [Qt should provide support](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats) for `jpg/jpeg` - i.e. without needing third-party plugins from KDE.

Comment: On Arch Linux, using Qt-4.8.7 and PySide-1.2.4, I get the same list, but with the following additions: `gif, ico, jpeg, jpg, mng, svg, svgz, tif, tiff, webp`. So it would seem that there are quite a few other image formats missing from the list shown on your system. My plugins look very similar, except I don't have *libqtga.so*, but I do have *kimg_webp.so*. Have you actually tried loading images for the formats missing in your list?

Comment: Well, it looks like upgrading to python 2.7.6 and Qt 4.8.7 made this problem go away. I remain puzzled, but am no longer stuck without JPEG support on this platform.